# Redirecting back to web page after User has clicked cancel

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

I integrated facebook login through laravel/socialite and its working fine.

The problem is when user clicks `cancel` in the popup from facebook, the screen will stayed on facebook's page itself instead of redirecting to my site.

Is anywhere i need to specify the cancel redirecting url in facebook login app? I don't know how to handle this redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out the answer [here](https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html#.WGY6Hy_QeM8)

> Just for other who are wondering, I just figured out a way... In
>   SocialAuthController: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`
>
> Then make constructor as:
>
> ```
> protected $request;
> public function __construct (Request $request) {
>     $this->request = $request;
> }
> ```
>
> and then in callback() function:
>
> ```
> if (isset($this->request['error'])) { 
>     return redirect()->to('/error');
>     //make your error route or do whatever you want!! 
> } else {
>     // this is my code, your actual code will go here on success
>     print_r($service);
>     $service = new SocialAccountService();
>     $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver($provider));
>     $providerUser = \Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
>     print_r($providerUser);
>     auth()->login($user);
>     return redirect()->to('/home'); 
> }
> ```